# NX9000 Port channel <> Debian Server Bond Issue

Tags: debian, bonding

I have an issue as mentioned in the title with an NX9000 port channel config to a Debian Server Bond config. 2 out of the 3 interfaces which are configured in the port channel on the NX (lets call is NX1) are suspended(no LACP PDUs seen on interfaces).

To give an idea on the setup, I have 2 NX9000's (lets call them NX1 and NX2) connected via VPC peering and the VPC towards the server is configured correctly. On the NX1 to the debian server, the following is seen for the interfaces in the port channel:

```
NX1# sh int status | i sus
Eth1/3  CDN temp 2 suspended trunk auto auto 10Gbase-SR
Eth2/20 CDN temp 1 suspended trunk auto auto 10Gbase-SR
```

On the lacp neighbor info we see the following (I do notice that the neighbor interfaces with the issues are in SP mode):

```
ELSO-TV01# sh lacp neighbor interface port-channel 4
Flags: S - Device is sending Slow LACPDUs F - Device is sending Fast LACPDUs
A - Device is in Active mode P - Device is in Passive mode
port-channel4 neighbors
Partner's information
Partner Partner Partner
Port System ID Port Number Age Flags
Eth1/36 65535,ac-1f-6b-9e-1d-b00x3 203073 FA

LACP Partner Partner Partner
Port Priority Oper Key Port State
255 0xf 0x3f

Partner's information
Partner Partner Partner
Port System ID Port Number Age Flags
Eth1/3 0,0-0-0-0-0-0 0x0 203073 SP

LACP Partner Partner Partner
Port Priority Oper Key Port State
0 0x0 0x0

Partner's information
Partner Partner Partner
Port System ID Port Number Age Flags
Eth2/20 0,0-0-0-0-0-0 0x0 203073 SP

LACP Partner Partner Partner
Port Priority Oper Key Port State
0 0x0 0x0
```

To give context in what occurred, the port channel 4 was up and working before but there was an unexpected power outage which took the debian server offline for a short time. Upon booting up, we had this issue only with these interfaces connecting to the server.

(cisco support confirmed no issues with the switch side configs).

This is what the provider was able to send (below 4 of the 6 interfaces are up and the two which are down are enp131s0f1 and enp2s0f0). Below gives a snip of the config with a working and not working interface in the bond.

```
DebianServer# ethtool enp131s0f1 (NOT WORKING)
Settings for enp131s0f1:
Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
Supported link modes: 1000baseT/Full
10000baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes: 1000baseT/Full
10000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 10000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Auto-negotiation: on
Port: FIBRE
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Supports Wake-on: d
Wake-on: d
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
drv probe link
Link detected: yes

DebianServer# ethtool ens2f0 (WORKING INTERFACE)
Settings for ens2f0:
Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
Supported link modes: 1000baseT/Full
10000baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes: 1000baseT/Full
10000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 10000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Auto-negotiation: on
Port: FIBRE
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Supports Wake-on: d
Wake-on: d
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
drv probe link
Link detected: yes
```

This is the bond file output on server (example of working interface. NOTE: enp131s0f1 and enp2s0f0 are missing from this file):

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v5.10.0-20-amd64

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer3+4 (1)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 200
Down Delay (ms): 200
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: fast
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: ac:1f:6b:9e:1d:b0
Active Aggregator Info:
Aggregator ID: 1
Number of ports: 4
Actor Key: 15
Partner Key: 32772
Partner Mac Address: 00:23:04:ee:be:0a

Slave Interface: ens2f0
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: ac:1f:6b:9e:1d:b0
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0
details actor lacp pdu:
system priority: 65535
system mac address: ac:1f:6b:9e:1d:b0
port key: 15
port priority: 255
port number: 1
port state: 63
details partner lacp pdu:
system priority: 32667
system mac address: 00:23:04:ee:be:0a
oper key: 32772
port priority: 32768
port number: 589
port state: 61
```